# Couldnt make ScrollTop affect Transform via CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations, scrolltop

im trying to make a ball (div with 50% radius) roll left with the user's scroll,
I have managed to make him move left according to ScrollTop but cant make the transform work the same way, where did i go wrong? this is the code with left working and transform not:

```
function parallax(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();    
    $('.ball').css('left', (scrolled * 0.9) + 'px');
    $('.ball').css('transform', rotate(scrolled * 180) + 'deg');
}
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    parallax();
});
```

Thank you for you answers!
Shir

Comment: Are you just missing quotes on `rotate(scrolled * 180)`? Seems like it should be `'rotate(' + (scrolled * 180) + 'deg)'`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, this also doesnt work, tried it before and tried it also now, copy paste to your line. it also disables the left from working..

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not support the transform property very well.

For rotations I would reccomend using the jQuery rotate plugin

https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Very easy to use, the syntax is something like this

`$('.ball').rotate(scrolled * 180)`

Answer (score 0):

Try [This](http://jsfiddle.net/9V2g4/). Hope it helps.

Jquery:

```
$('.ball').toggleClass("rotate-180");
```

CSS:

```
.rotate-180 {
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```